# Yii 2 Routing all request to invalid request page expect certain actions

Tags: php, yii2

I have 2 controllers with some actions, I want to all requests expect those actions in the 2 controllers to be routed to invalid request page, how can I do that?

suppose:

controller1 => action1, action2, action3 allowed

controller2 => action4, action5, action6 allowed

all other requests should be go to bad request page.

Thank you.

Comment: [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [gmc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2436306/gmc) specified you should use [Access Control](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html) , however you might want to specify the "bad request" page.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['action1', 'action2', 'action3'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
            ],
            'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
                 return $this->redirect(['controller/action']);
            }
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Access Control](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html), e.g. for controller 1:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['action1', 'action2', 'action3'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                // everything else is denied
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```